# Making this simple code threadsafe

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

I have just had a really good use for multithreading.  As such.... I have to learn multithreading.  I have a very simple program:

```
void *listenloop(void *arg){

    while (1){
       Sleep(2000);
       puts("testing 123\n");
   }
   return NULL;
}


int main(){
pthread_t listener;
pthread_create(&listener,NULL,listenloop,"foo");
char testinput[200];
while(1){
    puts("Scanning: ");
    scanf("%s",testinput);
    puts("\n\n");
    printf("You typed: %s: ",testinput);
}
```

}

The theory is that it waits for user input, echos it, all while periodically printing.

None to my surprise, actually (and presumably obviously to my betters in the matter) the output is "messed up."

Now I can think of several ways *around* this problem, but no actual solutions.  How should something of this nature be implemented?  Can it just be done by manipulating the output of the program after it is displayed to the user?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean the output is messed up?  looks like it should be fine to me.  Show us exactly what it does and what you want it to do.  Also there is no "post de facto"

Comment: Sorry guys.  Fixed the code...

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, there should be no "messed up" output (caused by threading, anyway) in that code as only the *one* thread (the main one) is doing any output.

The only thing the other thread does is infinitely loop with a delay of some sort.

Now that you've updated the question to output from the other thread then, yes, it *is* possible for the output to intermix.

There are several ways around this, two spring to mind immediately.

1. Have all output go through a series of functions which mutex-protect the output stream, such as `mutexed_printf()/mutexed_puts()` (which you'll need to provide) <sup>(a)</sup>.
2. Do all output from *one* of the threads, meaning the other will have to send data to it via some means (inter-thread communications like a queue) - that way all output can be properly mixed, such as on newline boundaries.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Also keep in mind that, if you want to mutex protect the output stream for the user input operation, you'll probably want to protect the `puts/scanf` atomically so that the testing output doesn't mess up your input (by outputting messages after the prompt but before/during your input). That won't be possible with a `mutexed_puts()` function, you'll need an expanded `mutexed_prompt_and_input()` one.

Comment: This isn't really an answer and should just be a comment.

Comment: @xaxxon, it _was_ an answer, stating that what the OP thought was happening could not possibly happen. There's ample precedent on SO for this. In any case, now that the question has been edited, the extra info I added to the answer makes this a useful answer in my opinion. Hopefully you'll agree.

Comment: usually when that happens it simply means they mis-copied some code.  A simple comment stating that the code doesn't do what they say is generally considered the right approach, hence a flag for exactly this type of non-answer.

Comment: First you copy my comment with an "answer" then you repost my answer?  Tacky.

Comment: xaxxon, I suggest you look again. My mutex solution was not to pepper the code with locks as per yours, but to provide modified implementations of the output functions with localised locking, reducing the need for lock management in the calling code. And that was only one of two possibilities, both of which were added because of the question edits rather than your answer. ...

Comment: ... However, since I seem to have offended you somehow, I gather you won't be removing the downvote even though the reason for it is long gone :-) You would be better off looking at your _own_ answer and fixing it so (1) it compiles; and (2) it fixes the intermix problem during input.

Answer (score 0):

So just wrap the prints in pthread_mutex_lock/unlocks with a single pthread_mutex_t and you should be fine.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock

```
pthread_mutex_t = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 

void *listenloop(void *arg){

    while (1){
       Sleep(2000);
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       puts("testing 123\n");
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }
   return NULL;
}


int main(){
pthread_t listener;
pthread_create(&listener,NULL,listenloop,"foo");
char testinput[200];
while(1){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    puts("Scanning: ");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    scanf("%s",testinput);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    puts("\n\n");
    printf("You typed: %s: ",testinput);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem with output appearing during the input operation, nor does it even compile. You should generally check code that you post here to ensure it is usable.